# How to make edittext scrollable, multiline and turn off auto suggest?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing a programming language code editor for the same I need `EditText` horizontally scrollable also multiline and I want to turn off the `autocorrect` and the `autosuggest`. Suppose, I want to write

```
int main(){ 
    printf("This is an awesome platform! I can get any problem solved here!");
}
```

then `EditText` should show in the exact same way. Like shown in the below image

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axmAP.jpg)

Dots at the end of the line denotes that it should be scrollable horizontally.

I tried this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_below="@id/label_code"
    android:id="@+id/et_code"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiline"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:background="@drawable/square_border_unselected"
    android:padding="15dp" />
```

But in that case, horizontal scroll is not working. The text is going to next line if it's length is more than screen size.

Is there any solution to implement all three features in `EditText`?

**Edit #1:**

If I don't use `textMultiline` than I am able to achieve horizontally scrollable EditText

**Update #1**

This is not the perfect solution but through this I achieved what I wanted.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minEms="1000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top" 
        android:padding="15dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:inputType="text"` will do the job for you!

```
<EditText
            android:text="This is an awesome platform! I can get any problem solved here!"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#876"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

---

**EDIT:**  Here goes  what  you want! Horizontal scroll with multi line.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#876"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:text="This is an awesome platform! I can get any problem solved here!"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

out put:

[image]

**EDIT3** : This is nothing but because you are lazy.Adjust bounds like below!

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <EditText
          android:background="#789"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:layout_width="500dp"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
  </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Cheers!

Comment: In that case I am able to achieve horizontally scrollable EditText but the google keyboard is showing tickmark instead of nextline option. So user won't be able to go to next line.

Comment: You can set imeoptions `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` and replace `actionDone`

Comment: Not able to find any attribute for the next line symbol

Comment: @Raj from Team Algoholic didn't get that can you bit elaborate what happens when you use  `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

Comment: Please see the question again I added the Image what exactly I want to do. If I use `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` then it is taking me to next `EditText` which is stdin. But I want next line in same `EditText`

Comment: Hi this is working because we are giving text attribute. Remove it form xml and then the same problem is there. As this is code editor so user will be typing we are not going to provide pre-written code.

Comment: @Raj from Team Algoholic  Man i can't spoon feed you.You should try this out add a parent layout to edit text and make it match parent then it works .come on grow up!!!

Comment: @Raj from Team Algoholic anything else?

Comment: Managed with this


`<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:minEms="1000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="top" 
        android:padding="15dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>`

Comment: Is it possible to have `minWidth="PARENT_SIZE"` I searched a lot but not getting any result

Comment: @Raj from Team Algoholic  .No.minWidth="PARENT_SIZE" does not sense.Isnt it.If its min equals to parent size that means that **minimum has reached to the maximum level**.Did you get that. Then you can use match_parent insted

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. `minEps` works for my application use

Comment: minEps in your EditText  ensure it's at least 1000 characters wide :) okay then good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

in your `EditText` xml.

Comment: Tried but it is not working still it is going to next line

Answer (score 0):

try these lines in your edittext
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:maxLines="10"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"

Comment: But I don't want to put limit on number of lines also I want horizontally scroll-able

Comment: then remove max lines

Comment: by default ,, edittext is multiline , you even no need to specify inputtype ,because inputtype limits the edit text... just add scrollbars to vertical and will be set.

Comment: and this maxLines="10" is not to limit edittest but it is ued that how much lines hown to user at once i.e. on single look...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your editText in a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

The combination of XML attributes that removed both the Suggestions and the Suggestions Bar while retaining multi-line text was the following:

```js
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions | textMultiLine"
```

or

```js
android:privateImeOptions="nm"
android:inputType="textFilter | textMultiLine"
```